# Show control and handle large rows for QTableView

Tags: qt, widget, controls, qtableview

I am implement a chat application (like skype)
I am using QTableWidget to display chat messages, but it’s too slow when display many messages (because each message is a widget, so if my chat has 1000 messages, it’ll create 1000 widgets and add to qtablewidget .. too slow and cost memory much :( )

I tend to change on QTableView, I have read docs and see QTableView is very good for display large message, but it’s hard to display control which I can interact.
ex: I need display a text which I can select and button which I can click, v..v.
but using paint is not enough, it’s just … paint pixel, not the real control and I can’t select my text or click button.

I had search and try some solution like setIndexWidget, but this way seem … like QTableWidgets (because it will create 1000 buttons if I have 1000 message as well)

Is anyone can suggest me some instructions :(
Thanks you

---

I had implement a sample qtable widgets can display control with reuseable widgets (base on the idea of modal-view-controller)
But it's not complete +_+
Please check this for more details:
https://github.com/tranquan/KJTableView

Comment: Yes, QTableView can display large amounts of data. All you need is do define you own delegate to display your message form. With buttons etc. And I think you have to show this form only when user click on it for example. And sow text in all other cases.

Comment: I need to show controls: label, button, progress, ... on viewmode, not editmode :(

Comment: Anyway, QTableView paints only visible items, not all the list.

Comment: You shouldn't create 1000 widgets. Qt can't work with such amount of widgets. Instead create buttons only for visible rows. Catch scroll bar events and move buttons when the table is scrolled. To place the buttons in the right place use `visualRect` method to retrieve cell coordinates.

Comment: @Ezee: Yeah, I have same ideas like you. I implement custom tableview with delegate and model. 
I made 30 reuseable widgets and add them in tableview's viewport
In delegate's paint: instead of drawing, I re-set geometry for widgets for display them
But this way is not complete +_+! (I currently work on this). this is some problems:
+ how many resuseable widgets I should create is enough ?
+ how to make delegate more general for I can implement other widgets ?
+ ... and many
Please check this for more details:
https://github.com/tranquan/KJTableView

Comment: _how many resuseable widgets I should create is enough_  You can calculate it or create on demand `getCloseButton(n)`. _how to make delegate more general for I can implement other widgets_ You can do it in a lot of ways. For example, pass a list of widgets description  in the constructor of the delegate. A description can contain a function creating a widget and a place where it should be places in a message.